# clang-format: always break if params don't fit?

Tags: clang, clang-format

I can't figure out if it's possible to configure clang-format to always break if parameters don't fit, ie:

```
// Try this first:
SomeCall(aaa, bbb, ccc);

// If doesn't fit, try this:
SomeCall(
     aaa, bbb, ccc);

// If still doesn't fit, do NOT try this:
SomeCall(aaa, bbb,
         ccc);

// and NOT this:
SomeCall(aaa,
         bbb,
         ccc);

// but immediately do this:
SomeCall(
     aaa,
     bbb,
     ccc);
```

So far I've concluded that it's not possible to do this with clang-format 3.4. Is it correct?

Comment: Also we need clang-format tag, but I can't add one.

Comment: I almost need the same kind of formatting.
When breaking into multiple lines I would like to put the first argument on the next line with a single indentation

Comment: It's formatting [@KevlinHenney](https://twitter.com/KevlinHenney) mentions in response to one of [Seven Ineffective Coding Habits of Many Programmers](http://www.slideshare.net/Kevlin/seven-ineffective-coding-habits-of-many-programmers-45312038/20).

Comment: Indeed!  I just learned of the existence of clang-format last night and downloaded it first thing this morning.  After figuring out how to map to ^K in vim, the next thing on my agenda was research how to configure for function argument continuations just as you describe. Need to dig into it and see if there's a good way to extend the configuratiability.

Answer (score 17):

In newer version of clang-format, this can now be achieved with:

```
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
```

See https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html for a full explanation of these options.

Comment: This works great for arguments (function call), do you have a solution for parameters (function declaration) as well? Many thx!

Answer (score 1):

I unfortunately only have access to `clang-format` 3.8.0 ("`clang-format version 3.8.0 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)`"), so I can't do testing easily for release 3.4.

There's a manual for the latest release of `clang-format` available [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) that I don't know if you've found or not. It links to the list of [Clang-Format Style Options](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html). In there, there's a style option that echoes the title of your question: `AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak`, *Always break after an open bracket, if the parameters don’t fit on a single line*.

To use this, put the following in your `~/.clang-format` file:

```
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
```

After some testing, it appears that it is doing exactly what you would want it to do, almost.

It formats

```
SomeCall(aaa, bbb, ccc);
```

as

```
SomeCall(
  aaa, bbb,
  ccc);
```

if `aaa, bbb, ccc` doesn't fit on one line. It will not break between `aaa` and `bbb` until `aaa` also is too long, in which case `bbb` and `ccc` will be on the same line. I.e. it breaks after the opening `(`, but then tries to fill lines.  It doesn't automatically break on all commas.

Looking at [corresponding page](http://llvm.org/releases/3.4/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for `clang-format` 3.4, it appears as if this configuration option sadly isn't there. This leaves you with two options:

1. Upgrade to a newer version of `clang-format`.
2. Don't.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @Daniel Kiss, the correct configuration to achieve your requested format is:

```
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
```

To inspect the behaviour of those configurations on your example code, using the following command:

```
echo 'SomeCall(aaa, bbb, ccc);' \
    | \
    clang-format-14 \
        --Werror \
        --style="{\
            AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak, \
            BinPackParameters: false, \
            BinPackArguments: false, \
            ColumnLimit: 1 \
            }"
```

For `ColumnLimit` between 1 to 18 the output is:

```
SomeCall(
    aaa,
    bbb,
    ccc);
```

For `ColumnLimit` between 19 to 23 the output is:

```
SomeCall(
    aaa, bbb, ccc);
```

For `ColumnLimit` greater than or equal to 24 (or equal 0) the output is:

```
SomeCall(aaa, bbb, ccc);
```