# How to configure clang-format alignment when breaking chains?

Tags: c++, indentation, code-formatting, clang-format

Please consider the following source file that has been formatted by clang-format 9.0.0:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using Type1 = std::pair<double, double>;
    using Type2 = std::vector<Type1>;
    using Type3 = std::vector<std::pair<int, Type2>>;
    using Type4 = std::tuple<size_t, size_t, Type3>;
    using Type5 = std::vector<Type4>;
    using Type6 = std::vector<Type5>;
    std::vector<int> name1234;
    int aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa = 0;
    int bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb = 0;
    int cccccccccccccc = 0;
    int dddddddddddddddddd = 0;

    Type6 eeeeeeeeeeeee;

    const double startParameterOfCheckedSegment = std::get<2>(
            eeeeeeeeeeeee.at(name1234.at(aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)).at(bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb))
                                                                                                        .at(cccccccccccccc)
                                                                                                        .second
                                                                                                        .at(dddddddddddddddddd)
                                                                                                        .first;

    std::cout << startParameterOfCheckedSegment << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The high indentation of line lines from `.at(cccccccccccccc)` on disturbs me very much. What is the reason for that and how can it be fixed?

My _clang-format file has the following contents:

```
Language: Cpp

AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: 'true'

BreakBeforeBraces: Allman

ColumnLimit: '80'

IndentWidth: '2'

NamespaceIndentation: None

Standard: Cpp11

TabWidth: '2'

UseTab: Always

PointerAlignment: Left

AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign

BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon

MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 2

AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None

AlignOperands: 'false'
```

Comment: Can you play with `ContinuationIndentWidth`?

Comment: @AndyG This seems to modify the strength of the effect, but it does not alter the behaviour itself.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966530/clang-format-always-break-if-params-dont-fit#47097008 Your problem is that the whole chain as you call it is just a single function parameter. And from what I can see there is no style option that is about breaking a single parameter.

Comment: @flowit Ah, thanks for the explanation. Indeed `AlignAfterOpenBracket ` seems to help. Strangely the value `Align` greatly improves the formatting. I had thought that I have to **suppress** alignment.